# Adding different suffix to end of the line

Tags: text-processing, files

I have a text file which contains this:

```
John
Jack
Jerry
```

I have another text file:

```
2017
2015
2018
```

And I want to make them like this:

```
John2017
John2015
John2018
Jack2017
Jack2015
Jack2018
Jerry2017
Jerry2015
Jerry2018
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux Stack Exchange.  It would appear that you have accidentally created two accounts.  You should use the [contact form](/contact) and select “I need to merge user profiles” to have your accounts merged.  In order to merge them, you will need to provide links to the two accounts.  For your information, these are https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/215567/cfem and https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/215568/cem.  You’ll then be able to [edit], comment on, and accept answers to this question.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that the files are small, it may be viable to read them into arrays (with `bash` or `ksh93`):

```
names=( $( <names.txt ) )
years=( $( <years.txt ) )
```

You may then construct a double loop that combines each name with each year in turn:

```
for n in "${names[@]}"; do
  for y in "${years[@]}"; do
    printf '%s%s\n' "$n" "$y"
  done
done
```

If `years.txt` is small, but `names.txt` is large:

```
years=( $( <years.txt ) )

while read n; do
  for y in "${years[@]}"; do
    printf '%s%s\n' "$n" "$y"
  done
done <names.txt
```

Result:

```
John2017
John2015
John2018
Jack2017
Jack2015
Jack2018
Jerry2017
Jerry2015
Jerry2018
```

Treating the files as single-column, header-less, CSV files:

```
$ csvsql -H --query "SELECT * FROM names CROSS JOIN years" names.txt years.txt | sed -e '1d' -e 's/,//'
```

This performs a relational [cross join](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Cross_join) operation on the data in the two tables and then goes on to strip off the first line of the output along with all commas (`csvsql` creates properly formatted CSV with a header line and comma-separated values).

`csvsql` is part of  [`csvkit`](http://csvkit.readthedocs.io/).

Comment: Would be worth noting that in ksh93 / bash, `$( <names.txt )` does split+glob (split only in zsh). `bash` has `readarray` as a better way to read lines of a file into an array. `zsh` / `fish` shells have builtin support to do the cartesian product of 2 arrays (`$^a$^b` in zsh, `$a$b` in fish)

Answer (score 2):

```
$ join -j2 -t : names year | tr -d :
```

- join by a non existing field and remove the output field separators.

Field 2 is empty and equal for all the element in `names` and `year` so `join` will concatenate each name with all the years: it is in fact calculating the Cartesian product.

Comment: Clever. Though it only seems to work with GNU `join`. Replacing `-j 2` with `-1 2 -2 2` would make it standard, but even then I didn't find another implementation beside GNU's where that works.

Comment: To tell you the truth I just have access to Linux (GNU everything)... Gnu Join: Once more giving a good semantic to the "corner case" is a blessing to the humanity :-)

Answer (score 1):

The solution that @Kusalananda provided is superior to this one.  I provided it without fully thinking through what `$(cat ...)` does in terms of memory usage.  I'll leave it here for reference – it'll work and isn't terrible for if the files are small.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

for name in $(cat names); do
    for year in $(cat years); do
        echo "${name}${year}"
    done
done
```

Comment: The reason I didn't go for that solution, and why I mentioned _small_ files, was that the inner file (`years`) is read once for every line in the first file (`names`), which may be slow if the files have any kind of non-trivial size.

Comment: @Kusalananda Good point.  The reason that I offered this alternative to your solution was that if the files are _large_, reading them into memory may not be a good option either.

Comment: And what do you think `$(cat names)` does?

Comment: @G-Man Doh.  You're right, I was thinking about `$(cat names)` incorrectly.  @Kusalananda 's solution is better all around.